# Labeling the name of a file with a given numerical parameter

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

With python I can save a file labeling its name with a given parameter `t` in the following way

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure(1)
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
t=0.1
fig.savefig("filename%f.png" % t)
```

and the name of the saved figure will be something like "filename0.1000.png". 
How can I do the same with wolfram mathematica? 
In other words, what is the mathematica equivalent of `%f` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Mathematica* you can use [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html):

```
filenameTemplate = StringTemplate["filename`n`.dat"];
filename = filenameTemplate[<|"n" -> 1234|>]
(* "filename1234.dat" *)
```

This will create a `filename` with a number from the [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html):

```
<|"n" -> 1234|>
```

Comment: thanks, problem: I tried `Export[StringForm["filename``.dat", 2], file]` but the output was the following 
"First argument filename2.dat is not a valid file specification.", whereas if I directly write Export["filename2.dat",file] it works

Comment: @3sm1r I have update the answer, I forget that `StringForm` prints the string.

Comment: @m0nhawk Why the `number = 1;`? Also the output above is incorrect, should be `filename1234.dat`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi It was a redundant line, it takes the number from `Association` after the call. Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output to be exactly the same as in your example:

```
t = 0.1;
"filename" <> ToString@NumberForm[t, {1, 4}] <> ".png"
(* filename0.1000.png *)
```

EDIT

`StringTemplate` is better if you need to do multiple replacements within the string (less messy string concatenation) and avoids some duplication if you need to use the same template in different places in your code. But for the latter case it would be better to encapsulate the filename generation in a separate function.

`StringTemplate` has options for specifying a `CombinerFunction` and an `InsertionFunction`. The default `InsertionFunction` is `TextString` so there is no need for the `ToString`.

```
t = 0.1;
filenameTemplate = StringTemplate["filename`t`.png"];
filename = filenameTemplate[<|"t" -> NumberForm[t, {1, 4}]|>]
(* filename0.1000.png *)
```

And there is a whole lot more that can be done with the templating system. See the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WorkingWithTemplates.html) for details.

Comment: Ty, are there practical reasons to prefer ToString@NumberForm to StringTemplate or viceversa? Maybe your solution looks slightly more concise.

Comment: @3sm1r Answer edited with response to your question.